# SoundPool is very slow

Tags: android, soundpool

I am working on a game with sound effects. It easily runs at 60fps without sound playing. When I play a sound, the frame takes about 50ms more to run than usual and there is a noticeable delay in the game. I am loading my sounds in the onResume method and playing them later. They are ogg files (tried mp3 as well). When the sound plays, I get several lines in the logcat about the audio manager working. I am testing on a HTC G2.

What could cause such a delay, and how can I fix it?